# Angularjs validation with expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, expression

I'm trying to implement input validation by angular expression ,I need to do that because i'm going to get validation data from database.

So I'm trying the following code

conttroller

```
    vm.key="ng-required"
    vm.value="true"
```

html

```
<input  type="text" name="field" ng-model="name" {{vm.key}}="{{vm.value}}" >
```

but this make no change.

Comment: Can you update your post with how the (meta-)data about the validation rules would look like? I feel this is a proper case for model validation (in contrast to UI validation) with something like [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron). If you provided more details, I could set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `{{}}` directive to create attribute dynamically(it will not work), and I don't think so that would be correct approach to do it. I'd like to suggest slight different way to deal with such validation, like you could take use of angular inbuilt directive like `ng-minlength`, `ng-maxlength`, `ng-required`, etc. which does take expression as their attribute values.

like for case it would be something like

```
ng-required="vm.value"
```